# Working on an AngularJS simple app

Tags: angularjs

I am new on AngularJS. I am working on a project from a Udemy course.

When I add this code on my app.js:

```
weatherApp.config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.htm',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })

    .when('/forecast', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/forecast.htm',
        controller: 'forecastController'
    }) 
});
```

i get this error on the browser console:
[Error: [$compile:tpload]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POxmT.png)

Even if I download the code from the course link i get the same error. Any ideas why happen this?

Comment: do you have `home.htm` files (templates)? Also, are they `.htm` or `.html`?

Comment: Yes i have, they are on the folder pages! They are both .htm

Comment: Can you provide code somewhere on plunker?

Comment: @NikolaosTzimpoulas can you share your folder structure? Maybe you are failing to reach `pages/`

Comment: Are you accessing to your Angular app with file explorer? It seems there's CORS issue on your side

Comment: @AnilKumarArya first time using plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/54pC5M9edll3iV5KeXuR

Comment: @AlekseySolovey On a Starter folder are my index.htm , app.js and a folder(pages) and in pages folder are these 2 htm files

Comment: @NikolaosTzimpoulas : Please check it here  https://plnkr.co/edit/o4gsEw?p=preview

Comment: and try hosting files locally using some server

Comment: @AnilKumarArya Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser is hindering your `home.htm` from running scripts that makes ajax call to another origin when opened via file path. There are countless resources explaining the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

If you serve your `home.htm` file with e.g. [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) you can navigate to the default url and port: `0.0.0.0:8080/home.htm`. Note that you might also have to add the `--cors` flag found in the docs.